# How can I tactfully point out that a colleague's work is bad?

Tags: refactoring, teamwork

As my first job, I joined a startup with a small number of developers.

I mainly work with this one other person -- let's call him Paul for now. We are the only two devs on our team.

He joined the company a year before I did, pretty much at its inception, and built a considerable part of our company's core and gets a lot of approval from management.

However, looking into his code, I realize it's *bad*. I mean *really bad*.

He sort of crash-learned programming in a few months, and to be honest, he's still a bad programmer. He doesn't know how to do list comprehension (we use `python` mostly), class inheritance (or anything relating oop), and doesn't know how to use git.

For instance, currently one of his old codes is taking 2 hours to complete a cron job, which does a huge list of `if` statements which I'm sure could be narrowed down to 10 minutes using regular expressions.

But obviously workplace politics exist, and I can't just blatantly say his code is the crux of our problems so pointedly. My team leader doesn't know how to code, and besides, I can't just say "he really just sucks at coding, and his code is terrible."

However, problems need to be amended -- and at some point, I feel like I need to say "your code really sucks, and I need to rewrite it, because you'll still do an awful job refactoring it".

How to bring this up tactfully?

Comment: This isn't a Software Engineering problem; it is a human relations problem.  I suggest The Workplace or Interpersonal Relations Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Robert Harvey. Very tactful, Robert. Very tactful.

Comment: @MartinMaat: I appreciate the compliment, if that's what that is.  I also appreciate the sarcasm, if that's what it actually is.

Comment: Have you asked him why he wrote the code the way he did?  Are you using a pull-request style workflow where you can propose specific improvements and have discussion?  Personally I have found over the years that it's best not to get too worked up over co-worker's code if it's doing its job.  If it's causing a problem (eg a 2 hr cronjob) then maybe the problem is worth fixing.  In that case just fix it and don't waste time laying blame.  It can be hard to tell between "actually bad code" and "not how I'd have done it." A problem-solving focus is a way around that pitfall.

Comment: Nothing you complain about in the question would increase the company's profitability though. A 2 hour cron job might cost a couple pennies more than a 10 minute version per execution, unless its failing a lot (which isn't stated in the question). OOP is just one style of coding, it is absolutely not necessary and can increase costs if not done correctly/clearly, and their proficiency with Git has nothing to do with the cost/benefit of refactoring existing code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and have a conversation (with your colleague, or management) about code quality, but if your colleague has a track record of delivering *sufficient* quality, then they are likely to fall on deaf ears unless management had already detected the problem for themselves.

Beware management who are not interested in things being done "properly" or being maintainable for the future if it comes at a cost (unless you are actually a faster and more thorough developer, not merely slower and more thorough).

The vast majority of code written is poor quality, short lived, and a reinvention of the wheel, and supports businesses whose operations are usually similarly poor quality, short-lived, and doing the same as many other businesses, and bosses are typically maximising their profit (at least in the short term) by underinvesting in code.

Also, execution time is not a significant guide to the quality of code - the bosses are not paying the computer by the hour, they are paying the developer by the hour.

Quality only emerges in the competitive market when there are regulations to monitor and enforce it, and that applies whether you're adulterating bread with chalk and plaster, or whether you are designing the systems by which a business is administered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have everything you need to get change happening.

Pick a point in the codebase that currently causes problems, e.g. taking much too long, and declare that it should be rewritten to make it faster. No need to call your coworker a "bad programmer" to get this done; in fact it could be better to explain "this was written in a great hurry, we should now invest the man-hour to redo it properly". Unless your goal is to get rid of the other guy or to gain status in the eyes of management, that is all that's necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are not this person's boss/manager, and presumably are not employed to be responsible for the quality of their work, this is something which can only be dealt with through management.

Of course, quality of work in any setting is something which should concern any business and any manager, since it generally affects things like customer satisfaction, revenue, time spent, ability to meet deadlines, the reputation of the business, and various levels of risk or threats to its future operation/profitability.

However, such issues are for discussion with the team leader/manager - there is no other way to approach this than to work with the decision-makers because they are the only ones empowered to prevent it happening (For example, you could help out your co-worker, but then that person might leave and get a better job, and then the employer may just hire someone else who is as bad or worse, and you'll be right back at square one again).

Management are the people who bear the ultimate responsibility for the quality of the work that both you and he produce, as well as anyone else who joins; they "own" it - it is their place to decide things like who to hire, what the acceptable levels of quality are, and acceptable working practices, so your co-worker's performance and the quality of their work is a management responsibility.

It is entirely reasonable to raise issues with management if you feel that there are problems which they need to be aware of and which are having a negative effect on the business, but this must be approached from a business point-of-view and not a technical one.   Also be prepared to listen to management in case they have any good reason for not wanting to act or not wanting to improve things.

In any discussion, only raise the concrete results of the work itself and avoid discussing the person who created it (Again, because the problems could just as easily apply to someone else if they happened to hire another developer with exactly the same skill level; before the co-worker can improve, the company must be providing the drive to change, then the co-worker needs to follow afterwards because it will be at the behest of management to do so).

In any discussions, look at where mistakes, errors, sloppy work, bad working practices, etc. have had negative results or harmed the business.  Any half-competent manager should be intelligent enough to know who had been responsible without the need for such discussions to degenerate into a blame-game or finger-pointing.   The focus should also be on ways of improving these things and learning lessons - i.e. new working practices, tools and guidelines which can be put in-place to avoid these problems

For example, a very good way to improve quality can be to ensure that the "definition of done" for any new piece of work includes full automated test coverage.    You may be able to find other automation tools and techniques such as static code analysers which could help to improve quality too.   Again, focusing on the working practices and not the people;  also don't forget that even the very best software engineers always have loads of room for self-improvement too, so look at this as raising the bar for the company, not  a person.

Also make sure that you keep in mind that bad working practices are not always seen as a problem if customers are happy and the business is making a profit.  Changing minds requires concrete, coherent reasoning, which must be supported by empirical evidence - this may mean you will need to start with new/improved working practices on your own work so that you have demonstrable results of things getting better.

It is always really hard to make improvements - don't expect any change to happen quickly, and don't expect a smooth journey.    Ultimately you are an employee who needs to live up to (and maybe exceed) the salary you are paid.    Work collaboratively.   Keep an open mind.   Become an exceptional listener.   Be a strong communicator.    Be kind.   Be understanding.    Invest time in becoming an expert on the things you want to improve and the practices you want to introduce.     You can strive to be the person trying to educate others in the business (including management) on the virtues of good software development practices and sensible, realistic, pragmatic steps about how they can approach it and why.

Many non-technical people do not intuitively understand how software engineering issues tie into business issues;  indeed, many business people see "IT" as a necessary overhead which drains money;  be sensitive to their outlook.   Also realise that many technical people do not necessarily have a deep enough understand the typical business rationale for avoiding technical debt - at least not well enough to argue a business case for it anyway.

Chances are there are many people in the business who would all benefit from learning a lot more about software engineering, so consider trying to encourage them to read books such as The Mythical Man Month, The Pragmatic Programmer, and The Clean Coder.

And if you have not read those books yourself, then I would look to those for guidance;  if you want to be the agent of change then you need to deeply immerse yourself in books about software development practices, because you will have a lot of very difficult arguments to win; you can only win those arguments by being sure of the issues yourself - if nothing else, you can improve yourself even if those improvements do not change anything about the culture of the company.